# Hmisc: label a data.frame column with hms format

Tags: r, lubridate, hmisc

I'm trying to label a data.frame with one of the columns of the format 'hms', as follows:

```
library(Hmisc)

data <- data.frame(time = c(hms::hms(20, 20, 20), hms::hms(30, 20, 10)),
                   date = c(as.Date("2001/01/01"), as.Date("2001/01/01")))

label(data) <- list(time = "Time", date = "Date")
```

However, I get the following error when trying to view the data.frame in RStudio

```
Error in `as.character()`:
! Can't convert `x` <labelled> to <character>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The issue is with the `time` variable

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
attributes(data$time)$label <- "Time"
```

Comment: In deed, if you don't call other packages, label(data$time) <- "Time" works well. Maybe R mistakenly used "label" function in other packages. You may also try Hmisc::label(data$time) <- "Time" instead.